# Assigning a function to a boost::function member variable where it is defined requires constructor?

Tags: c++, c++11, boost-function

I am trying to assign a function to a boost::function in a class member variable definition:

```
#include <boost/function.hpp>

#include <iostream>

double Function0()
{
    std::cout << "Function0()" << std::endl;
    return 2.2;
}

template <typename T>
class MyClass
{
public:
    boost::function<double ()> MyFunctionPointer2 =
          &Function0; // doesn't work, unless I define a constructor

  // error: conversion from 'double (*)()' to non-scalar type 'boost::function<double()>' requested
    MyClass(){}
};

int main () 
{
  MyClass<int> a;

  return 0;
}
```

It works correctly, only if I defined the constructor. If you comment this line in the code below ("MyClass(){}"), the noted error is produced. Can anyone explain this behavior?

Comment: The compiler is g++ 4.7.2

Comment: Seems to have been fixed since [g++ 4.9.1](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/DT7dkLvqwPRSNSeZ)

Comment: Ok, so in 4.7.2 I just need to do this inside the constructor? If you make "This is a compiler bug" an answer, I can accept it.